# SQL / VB.NET - Query doesn't return to application

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I've got a MSSQL procedure running fine from the SQL Management console, but when I try to run it from my VB.NET it simply never returns. Someone have any idea?

- I am testing with the same database.

**SQL CODE (PROCEDURE)**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_DEN_L_IMPRESSAO_ORCAMENTOS_APROVADO_NOVO]
(
    @PAC_D_DATA_INICIAL DATETIME        = NULL,
    @PAC_D_DATA_FINAL   DATETIME        = NULL,
    @PAC_DET_N_CODIGO   DECIMAL         = NULL,
    @PAC_CLI_N_CODIGO   DECIMAL         = NULL,
    @PAC_EMP_N_CODIGO   DECIMAL         = NULL
)
AS

SELECT
    PAC_N_CODIGO,
    PAC_C_CODIGO_INTERNO,
    PAC_C_NOME,
    PAC_C_EMAIL,
    PAC_C_TELEFONE_RES,
    PAC_CLI_N_CODIGO,
    CLI_C_DESCRICAO,
    ODO_D_DATA_INICIO,
    ODO_D_DATA_FINAL,
    ODO_PTR_N_CODIGO,
    CASE PAC_N_CORRESPONDENCIA 
        WHEN 1 THEN
            PAC_C_ENDERECO_RES +
            CASE 
                WHEN PAC_C_NUMERO_RES IS NULL OR PAC_C_NUMERO_RES = '' THEN ''
                ELSE ', ' + PAC_C_NUMERO_RES
            END +
            CASE
                WHEN PAC_C_COMPLEMENTO_RES IS NULL OR PAC_C_COMPLEMENTO_RES = '' THEN ''
                ELSE ', ' + PAC_C_COMPLEMENTO_RES
            END
        WHEN 2 THEN
            PAC_C_ENDERECO_COM +
            CASE
                WHEN PAC_C_NUMERO_COM IS NULL OR PAC_C_NUMERO_COM = '' THEN ''
                ELSE ', ' + PAC_C_NUMERO_COM
            END +
            CASE
                WHEN PAC_C_COMPLEMENTO_COM IS NULL OR PAC_C_COMPLEMENTO_COM = '' THEN ''
                ELSE ', ' + PAC_C_COMPLEMENTO_COM
            END
    END AS PAC_C_ENDERECO,
    CASE PAC_N_CORRESPONDENCIA
        WHEN 1 THEN PAC_C_BAIRRO_RES
        WHEN 2 THEN PAC_C_BAIRRO_COM
    END AS PAC_C_BAIRRO,
    CASE PAC_N_CORRESPONDENCIA
        WHEN 1 THEN PAC_C_CIDADE_RES
        WHEN 2 THEN PAC_C_CIDADE_COM
    END AS PAC_C_CIDADE,
    CASE PAC_N_CORRESPONDENCIA
        WHEN 1 THEN
            (SELECT EST_C_RESUMIDO
            FROM DEN_EST_ESTADO
            WHERE EST_N_CODIGO = PAC_EST_N_CODIGO_RES)
        WHEN 2 THEN
            (SELECT EST_C_RESUMIDO
            FROM DEN_EST_ESTADO
            WHERE EST_N_CODIGO = PAC_EST_N_CODIGO_COM)
    END AS EST_C_RESUMIDO,
    CASE PAC_N_CORRESPONDENCIA
        WHEN 1 THEN PAC_C_CEP_RES
        WHEN 2 THEN PAC_C_CEP_COM
    END AS PAC_C_CEP,
    ODO_N_VERSAO,
    PAC_C_CELULAR,
    PAC_DET_N_CODIGO,
    ODO_N_CODIGO,
    SUM(VIN_N_VALOR) as 'T_PROC',
    (SELECT SUM(VIN_N_VALOR) FROM DEN_VIN_VINCULO_TRATAMENTO
        WHERE VIN_OXD_ODO_N_CODIGO = ODO_N_CODIGO) as 'VIN_N_VALOR',
    convert(decimal(18,2),0) AS 'T_ENTRADA'    
FROM
    DEN_PAC_PACIENTE
INNER JOIN 
    DEN_DET_DENTISTA 
ON
    DET_N_CODIGO = PAC_DET_N_CODIGO 
AND
    DET_CLI_N_CODIGO = PAC_CLI_N_CODIGO     
INNER JOIN 
    DEN_CLI_CLINICA 
ON
    CLI_N_CODIGO = PAC_CLI_N_CODIGO 
INNER JOIN 
    DEN_EMP_EMPRESA 
ON
    EMP_N_CODIGO = CLI_EMP_N_CODIGO     
INNER JOIN 
    DEN_ODO_ODONTOGRAMA 
ON
    ODO_PAC_N_CODIGO = PAC_N_CODIGO
INNER JOIN
    DEN_VIN_VINCULO_TRATAMENTO
ON
    VIN_OXD_ODO_N_CODIGO = ODO_N_CODIGO
WHERE
    (ODO_D_DATA_FINAL BETWEEN @PAC_D_DATA_INICIAL AND @PAC_D_DATA_FINAL) 
AND
    (ODO_PTR_N_CODIGO = 2) 
AND
    (ODO_B_APROVADO = 1) 
AND
    (@PAC_CLI_N_CODIGO IS NULL OR PAC_CLI_N_CODIGO = @PAC_CLI_N_CODIGO)
AND
    (@PAC_DET_N_CODIGO IS NULL OR VIN_DET_N_CODIGO = @PAC_DET_N_CODIGO)
AND
    (CLI_EMP_N_CODIGO = @PAC_EMP_N_CODIGO) 
AND
    (PAC_B_ATIVO = 1) 
AND
    (PAC_B_POTENCIAL = 0)   
GROUP BY
    PAC_N_CODIGO,
    PAC_C_CODIGO_INTERNO,
    PAC_C_NOME,
    PAC_C_EMAIL,
    PAC_C_TELEFONE_RES,
    PAC_CLI_N_CODIGO,
    CLI_C_DESCRICAO,
    ODO_D_DATA_INICIO,
    ODO_D_DATA_FINAL,
    ODO_PTR_N_CODIGO,
    ODO_N_VERSAO,
    PAC_C_CELULAR,
    PAC_DET_N_CODIGO,
    ODO_N_CODIGO,
    PAC_N_CORRESPONDENCIA,
    PAC_C_ENDERECO_RES,
    PAC_C_NUMERO_RES,
    PAC_C_NUMERO_RES,
    PAC_C_COMPLEMENTO_RES,
    PAC_C_ENDERECO_COM,
    PAC_C_NUMERO_COM,
    PAC_C_COMPLEMENTO_COM,
    PAC_C_BAIRRO_RES,
    PAC_C_BAIRRO_COM,
    PAC_C_CIDADE_RES,
    PAC_C_CIDADE_COM,
    PAC_EST_N_CODIGO_RES,
    PAC_EST_N_CODIGO_COM,
    PAC_C_CEP_RES,
    PAC_C_CEP_COM
ORDER BY
    PAC_C_NOME, ODO_N_VERSAO
```

**VB.NET CODE**

```
Public Function ListarOrcamentosAprovadoNovo(ByVal mdlPaciente As Paciente, _
                                                 ByVal datDataInicial As Date, _
                                                 ByVal datDataFinal As Date, _
                                                 ByVal pblnEtiqueta As Boolean, Optional ByVal pstrCodigos As String = "") As DataTable
            Try
                cmdCommand = New FWCommand

                With cmdCommand
                    .CommandText = "P_DEN_L_IMPRESSAO_ORCAMENTOS_APROVADO_NOVO"
                    .CommandTimeout = intCommandTimeOut
                    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                    .Parameters.Add(New FWParameter("@PAC_D_DATA_INICIAL", FWDbType.DateTime))
                    .Parameters("@PAC_D_DATA_INICIAL").Value = datDataInicial

                    .Parameters.Add(New FWParameter("@PAC_D_DATA_FINAL", FWDbType.DateTime))
                    .Parameters("@PAC_D_DATA_FINAL").Value = datDataFinal

                    If mdlPaciente.CodDentista > -1 Then
                        .Parameters.Add(New FWParameter("@PAC_DET_N_CODIGO", FWDbType.Decimal))
                        .Parameters("@PAC_DET_N_CODIGO").Value = mdlPaciente.CodDentista
                    End If

                    If mdlPaciente.CodClinica > 0 Then
                        .Parameters.Add(New FWParameter("@PAC_CLI_N_CODIGO", FWDbType.Decimal))
                        .Parameters("@PAC_CLI_N_CODIGO").Value = mdlPaciente.CodClinica
                    End If

                    If mdlPaciente.CodEmpresa > 0 Then
                        .Parameters.Add(New FWParameter("@PAC_EMP_N_CODIGO", FWDbType.Decimal))
                        .Parameters("@PAC_EMP_N_CODIGO").Value = mdlPaciente.CodEmpresa
                    End If
                End With

                Return conProvider.ExecuteDataTable(cmdCommand)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw
            Finally
                cmdCommand = Nothing
            End Try
        End Function
```

Comment: If it is working fine in SQL Server, then this procedure might be correct. Then you need to check your VB code. Or you can post your code in the question.

Comment: Try adding WITH RECOMPILE or OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN, depending on version of SQL Server, to the stored procedure and try again

Comment: Where is your [tag:vb.net] code???

Comment: I posted my vb.net code now. thanks!

Comment: @guinatal at this point you'd better off be using Sql Server Profiler.

Comment: You should use a `Using` block instead of a `Try ... Catch` block for `cmbCommand`

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. Check that your .NET connection string is pointing to the same database that
   you are using in your SSMS query
2. You are using different parameter values in you .NET code then when running in SSMS
3. This could be related to "parameter sniffing". Possible workarounds are

   a) adding `with(recompile)` to the proc,

   b) add a set of local variables that you copy the parameter values into and use the local variables in the query,

   c) use `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@VARIABLE UNKNOWN))`, or

   d) trace flag 4136 that can be used to disable the "parameter sniffing" process (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980653)

See these articles for more details on parameter sniffing:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx
http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx